# How to assign MLflow Tracking Server when running project via MLflow Projects with Docker?

Tags: python, docker, mlflow

**TLDR:**
I'm trying to execute *`mlflow run localhost:5000`* using Docker environment and it is resulting error as follows:

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here is the full error message:

> [Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUwno.png)

Seems like the *`mlflow`* is trying to establish ssh connection to locally container hosted MLflow Tracking Server.

It has no problem when specifying the tracking server in the same folder with the *`MLproject`* file (using dot '.' after *`mlflow run`* command, e.g. *`mlflow run .`*), but it creates its own tracking server and not using the tracking server that has been provided. Thus, the tracking things isn't logged to provided tracking server.

**The Details:**
I'm running **Windows 10** and **WSL Ubuntu 22.04.3**.
Docker installed in Windows using WSL backend.

The project folder containing:

**1. Dockerfile**
Required by MLflow Projects especially when using Docker environment.
Here is the content:

```
FROM python:3.11.7-slim-bullseye

RUN apt update &&\
apt upgrade -y &&\
pip install --upgrade pip &&\
pip install --upgrade setuptools &&\
pip install --upgrade wheel &&\
pip install mlflow numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn

WORKDIR /home
COPY train.py /home
```

**2. MLproject**
Configuration for the MLflow Projects.
Here is the content:

```
name: Iris Classifier

docker_env:
   image:  mlflow_docker

entry_points:
  main:
    command: "python train.py"
```

**3. docker-compose.yaml**
Just to simplify when building Docker image from Dockerfile.
Here is the content:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mlflow_docker:
    image: mlflow_docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: ./
    container_name: mlflow_docker
    hostname: mlflow_docker
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
```

**4. train.py**
The mockup training script.

> [Training Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vmnb.png)

**5. requirements.txt**
Just the list of installed packages.

**What I've tried :**

- Tried to run the tracking server without Docker container and assign the URI to *`mlflow run`* command. It still not make it.
- Changing the `localhost:5000` to `127.0.0.1:5000`, `0.0.0.0:5000`, and `host.docker.internal:5000` also won't works.
- Try to add git repository and push it to github, not working.

The only way to successfully running *`mlflow run`* is when specifying dot (.) in URI (e.g. *`mlflow run .`*)

**The Goal:**
I'm expecting to log the tracking things on another server (e.g. *`mlflow run localhost:5000`*).
I want to utilize the provided containerized MLflow tracking server (*`localhost:5000`*) when using MLflow Project (*`mlflow run`*).

Any suggestion would be appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: Update -------

After checking in MLflow source code and the documentation, the URI after _`mlflow run`_ is not intended to set the URI of tracking server (my bad, not carefully read the documentation), instead it is intended to tell the MLflow Projects where is the location of project that you wish to run. Passing argument like URL to this parameter makes MLflow think that it is a Github repository link. The only way to set the tracking server (AFAIK) is only from your script e.g. _`train.py`_.

Comment: Cont. ------- But new issue comes up after assigning Github URL (e.g. _`git@github.com:xxxx/yyy.git`_) or project path (e.g. _`./`_) to _`mlflow run`_ command, it is _`RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`_ exception. This is caused by MLflow Projects by default replacing the server tracking uri that has been set in script e.g. _`train.py`_ with environ _`MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI`_ when running Docker container. I've been trying to set those environ but not works, so I decided to delete those environ using _`os`_ library from Python in the very beginning of main function. With this way, my goal is achieved.